# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.getAllAppenders() when running docx4j

Tags: log4j, docx4j

I'm writing a simple program with docx4j but getting

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.getAllAppenders()
```

I do have log4j 1.2.15 installed (listed in docx4j's dependencies). Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: Check again that your log4j jar is on your classpath.  Otherwise, tell us more about your environment, and how you are starting your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by configuring docx4j.properties file:

```
# If you haven't configured log4j yourself
# docx4j will autoconfigure it. Set this to true to disable that
docx4j.Log4j.Configurator.disabled=true
```